# postgresql to_char(date, 'day') get different result when using nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

**UPDATE 2**

Using the suggestions from @Bergi, I added a db execution helper to set the timezone before executing the query. This allows me to control the timezone based on the logged in user's preferences.

```
async function execWithTZ(sql, params, timezone) {
  const client = await this.pool.connect();
  await client.query<any>(`SET TIMEZONE TO '${timezone}'`, []);
  return client.query<any>(sql, params);
}

const result = await execWithTZ('SELECT ...', [], 'Australia/Sydney');
```

**QUESTION**

I am trying to get Postgresql to return the day of the week of a specific date in a view. I later use this to display values by day.

The data is in a table with a column named `updated` which is a `timestamptz` field.

When running the following query using DBeaver SQL client against a PostgreSQL 12 database I get the values as I expect, with records updated on Thursday local time (just after midnight) showing up as Thursday

```
  SELECT 
        count(v.id) AS count,
        btrim(to_char(v.updated, 'DAY'::text)) AS day,
        date_trunc('DAY'::text, v.updated) AS "updatedDay"
 FROM table v
 GROUP BY (to_char(v.updated, 'DAY'::text)), (date_trunc('DAY'::text, v.updated))
```

I put this in a view and when I query this view using `node-postgres` the counts are for the previous day (Wednesday), which I presume is because the database thinks it should interpret the dates in the UTC timezone.

To further prove the point, when I change the above query to use `DAYTZ` instead of just `DAY` in DBeaver I get `THURSDAYAEST` but in nodejs as result I get `WEDNESDAYUTC`

Changing all my dates to be without timezone and forcing everything to UTC on the way in is not an option for me.

How can I make `node-postgres` tell the database what timezone I want these dates interpreted as so that I can get the correct day?

**UPDATE 1**

I managed to get PostgreSQL to return the correct values to `postgres node` by setting the database user's timezone.

```
ALTER ROLE visuo_ingest SET TIMEZONE TO 'Australia/Sydney';
```

Now the counts for things that happened on Thursday Sydney time is counted for Thursday and not Wednesday.

Still interested in a way to do this on the connection rather than the database user level.

Comment: I think it's Javascript which converts the SQL date string into Javascript date class which is UTC timezone. So, you may need to explicitly override the dates on how `node-postgres` translates the dates into Javascript objects, please refer https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/429#issuecomment-24870258

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the value WEDNESDAY comes back in a column from Postgreql. Postgreql is doing the date formatting and so conversion to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Still interested in a way to do this on the connection rather than the database user level.

You already found [the right setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE), there's no reason to alter it on a role only. You can also [change the setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html) in a client session by running the [`SET` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html)

```
SET TIMEZONE TO 'Australia/Sydney';
```

Just put that in a `pgClient.query("…");` right after connecting the client.

Comment: This works if I use a Postgresql client (such as DBeaver), but do you know how I can get the `node postgres` (https://node-postgres.com/) library to do this? I tried pre-pending my query with `SET TIMEZONE TO 'Australia/Sydney'; SELECT FROM ...` but that fails with parsing error.

I suppose I could try doing it using the connection string...

Comment: @dvanrensburg That should work. Iirc you cannot use parameterised queries with multiple statements, but really just make two subsequent queries using the same client instance.

Comment: @dvanrensburg What exactly is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Ah thanks Bergi, I'll try idea later today. I'll make a connection and then execute both queries in sequence without releasing it.